# How to bind two components from different lazy-loaded modules to the same route?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an Angular application with the structure as on the image:

[image]

In want to conditionally select one of the themes based on the data retrieved from the server.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: 'app/presentation/theme1/theme1.module#Theme1Module',
    canActivate: [Theme1Guard],
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: 'app/presentation/theme2/theme2.module#Theme2Module',
    canActivate: [Theme2Guard],
  }
];
```

Both `theme-1` and `theme-2` modules have the same routes to similar component with different layout and styles.

### UPDATE 1

I tried `CanActivate` guards one for `theme-1` and the second for `theme-2`. Each guard retrieves current theme name from the `themeStore` and compares it to the current route:

```
canActivate() {
    let currentTheme: string = '';
    this.themeStore.currentTheme.subscribe((themeName) => {
      currentTheme = themeName;
    });

    if (currentTheme == 'theme1') {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

However, this won't work because Angular router does not look for the same path after the first one was rejected by `CanActivate` guard.

### UPDATE 2

There's an open issue in Angular repository - [Load a component in a route depending on an asynchronous condition](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12088). It seems to be added to backlog a few months ago.

Comment: hello, are you importing the first module in the second one?

Comment: Hi, I'm lazy-loading `theme-1` and `theme-2` modules into `presentation` module.

Answer (score 2):

> Both theme-1 and theme-2 have the same route to similar component with
> different layout and styles.

### No lazy-loading

Create `theme-1` and `theme-2` routes:

```
{
    path: 'theme-1', component: Theme1Component,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'page', 
        component: PageComponent,
      }

    ]
},
{
    path: 'theme-2', component: Theme2Component,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'page', 
        component: PageComponent,
      }
    ]
},
```

### With lazy loading

If they are lazy loadable, then in main **route module**:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',     
    children: [
      {
        path: 'theme-1',         
        loadChildren: 'path/to/theme1#module',
      },
      {
        path: 'theme-2',         
        loadChildren: 'path/to/theme2#module',
      }

    ]
  },
  ...
];
```

Lazy-loading `theme-1`, `theme-2` module routes:

**theme1-routing.module:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: Theme1Component,

        children: [
            {
              path: 'page', 
              component: PageComponent,
            },           
        ]
    }
];
```

**theme2-routing.module:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: Theme2Component,

        children: [
            {
              path: 'page', 
              component: PageComponent,
            },           
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: In both scenarios you described there is a **theme-N** in URL. As I'm asking in the question, I need my routes to look like `/page`, not `/theme-1/page`. A user won't be able to see what the current theme is from the URL, a theme type is retrieved from the database record.

Comment: @SerhiiKalaida, So how will identify which theme is current? Should be some determination

Comment: That's the problem I'm looking for a solution to. Perhaps, I could managed this with `CanActivate` guard. This guard should accept only that route which belongs to the theme module, which name was retrieved from db.

Answer (score 0):

i think your route of the second module is overridden, try to put your routing in the first position in your imports for the second module:

```
 // in your second module
 imports: [
    routing, 
    ... // then import the others 
],
```

Comment: The the second route overrides the first one. I need both of them to work on the theme type retrieved from database.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 14.1+ you can use [`CanMatch` guards](https://angular.io/api/router/CanMatch) for this.

Lazy-loaded or not, if two routes share the same path there needs to be some condition to separate them. `CanActivate` runs only after the route is decided. With `CanMatch` this is simple, as it can be asynchronous, uses Angular's dependency injection like other guards, and can skip routes in the matching stage. It'll also add the functionality of `CanLoad`, as a route that can't be matched won't load its child routes.

Without `CanMatch`, you could replace `path` with `matcher` and provide a synchronous function that would return `true` for the right route.

Now the problem is that `UrlMatcher` is synchronous and has no dependency injection. There's a [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72848909/1726637) on a different question about this exact problem, and it includes workarounds for pre-`CanMatch` Angular versions.

Briefly, one workaround is adding a state variable that will be used in both of the matchers, updating it in `CanActivate`, and if the new value is different - redirecting so the routes will be matched again.

You'd also need to make sure the routes are matched in the first place, or there will be cases where the current state is not updated and no route will be matched. In the question's case it's already assured, as their child routes have the same path structure, but in other cases you could add a wildcard route that has the same guard that updates the state variable.