# Angular 6+ Dependency Injection & Async in UrlMatcher

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, routes

How can I inject dependencies for a route's `UrlMatcher` and perform asynchronous route matching?

I need to make a call to a back end API in order to find out the right route for each URL (by parsing rewrite rules and running queries in WordPress).

That's why I need a singleton service for the `UrlMatcher` to fetch the data once and then use it to determine the route (and then inject it to the component with the fetched data).

I created a UrlMatcher factory:

```
      {
        component: PostComponent,
        matcher: wpApiUrlMatcherFactory('post')
      }
```

But I don't know how to inject the same service to all of the matchers and how to make it work since the service is asynchronous and `UrlMatcher` can't return a `Promise` or an `Observable`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @mait.taim No, I ended up using a single top-component and [creating components dynamically](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) without a built-in router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short Answer

It's not directly possible with a `UrlMatcher`, but **in Angular 14.1 [the `CanMatch` route guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanMatch)** was introduced for this purpose. It lets you control whether a route should be used at all even if its `path` or `matcher` match, allowing to skip the route and match other routes. It supports dependency injection and can be asynchronous (return a `Promise` or an `Observable`). It can also return a `UrlTree` to cancel the navigation and redirect to another route.

**Alternatively**, for asynchronicity you can either:

1. **Use a guard like `CanActivateChild`** to perform the asynchronous operations when needed. You can then **redirect** (cancel the navigation by returning a `UrlTree`) and let the router match the routes again, this time with the updated data available synchronously in any `UrlMatcher` as explained below.
2. Handle some of your routing outisde of the Angular router by **[dynamically loading components](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)** inside a component.

As for dependencies in `UrlMatcher`, you can either keep the data itself in a global variable or **capture the injector** and keep that as a global variable, then use it in `UrlMatcher` to resolve the service. Either way the data access will be synchronous.

See below for more details and code examples.

### Background

DI-capable `UrlMatcher` and asynchronicity in the matching stage of routes have been requested and discussed for years (even back in Angular 2.0), most notably in the following issues on Angular's GitHub: [Load a component in a route depending on an asynchronous condition (#12088)](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12088) and [UrlMatcher as a service (#17145)](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17145). Both of those and others were marked as resolved following [the `CanMatch` pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/46021).

The previously existing router guards (such as `CanActivate`, `CanLoad` and `Resolve`) run only *after* the route is chosen/recognized (*in its entirety*, including child routes), thus not suitable for deciding *where* to navigate based on some data from a service, at least not directly (without redirecting). Furthermore, they don't solve the DI issue in `UrlMatcher` so you'd need to resort to keeping the data in a global variable that gets updated asynchronously, or to capturing the injector.

### `CanMatch` guard (Angular 14.1+)

Although `UrlMatcher` still can't return a promise or an observable, `CanMatch` can be used for that purpose.

`CanMatch` guards run after a route is matched using `path` or `matcher` but before it is considered recognized and before other guards run. If all such guards resolve to `true` for a given route (from the root route to the innermost child route) it will be recognized, and other types of guards will be called. If a `CanMatch` guard resolves to `false` the route will be skipped, and the router will attempt to match the next route. It can also resolve to a `UrlTree` for a navigation cancel and redirect.

At the time of writing, `CanMatch` guards get called multiple times per navigation, like `UrlMatcher` ([UrlMatcher is called twice (#26081)](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26081)). It's just another reason to consider reusing the results of the asynchronous operations there across duplicate subsequent requests and perhaps managing some cache.

1. An example with different routes for the same URL using `CanMatch`:

   ```ts
   @Injectable()
   class CanMatchAdmin implements CanMatch {
     constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

     canMatch(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean> {
       // might wait for an API call
       return this.auth.user$.pipe(
         map(user => user.isAdmin)
       );
     }
   }
   ```

   ```ts
   const routes = [
     {
       path: '',
       component: AdminDashboardComponent
       canMatch: [CanMatchAdmin]
     },
     {
       path: '',
       component: UserDashboardComponent,
       canMatch: [CanMatchLoggedIn]
     },
     {
       path: '',
       pathMatch: 'full',
       redirectTo: 'login'
     },
     // ...
   ];
   ```
2. An example for the specific question's use case:

   ```ts
   @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
   class CanMatchWpApi implements CanMatch {
     constructor(private wp: WpApiService) {}

     async canMatch(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): Promise<boolean> {
       const data = await this.wp.getByUrl(segments.join('/'));
       return data.contentType === route.data.wpContentType;
     }
   }
   ```

   ```ts
   // Wildcard routes (**) do not seem to allow subsequent routes
   // so we'll use a UrlMatcher that consumes the entire path
   const anyUrlMatcher: UrlMatcher = (segments) => ({ consumed: segments });

   const routes: Routes = [
     // ...
     {
       path: '',
       children: [
         {
           path: ':categorySlug/:postSlug',
           component: PostComponent,
           canMatch: [CanMatchWpApi],
           data: { wpContentType: 'post' },
         },
         {
           path: ':parentPageSlug/:pageSlug',
           component: PageComponent,
           canMatch: [CanMatchWpApi],
           data: { wpContentType: 'page' },
         },
         {
           matcher: anyUrlMatcher,
           component: SomeFunkyComponent,
           canMatch: [CanMatchWpApi],
           data: { wpContentType: 'some_funky_content_type' },
         },
         // ...
       ],
     },
     // ...
   ];
   ```

### Alternatives

1. A combination of other guards (specifically `CanActivate` or `CanActivateChild`) and redirects. Keep in mind that in order for these guards to be run the route needs to be matched first. This may seem unintuitive at first, so consider that all of the competing routes will have that guard, and it will redirect when it detects the data used to match the current route is not right. The redirect will cause a rerun of the route matching, with the updated URL data now available synchronously in the route matchers. The example from the question can be implemented roughly like this:

   ```ts
   let wpData = null;
   let wpDataUrl = null;
   ```

   ```ts
   @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
   class CanActivateChildWpApi implements CanActivateChild {
     constructor(private router: Router, private wp: WpApiService) {}

     async canActivateChild(
       route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
       state: RouterStateSnapshot
     ): Promise<boolean> {
       const url = state.url;

       // Pass if the data used to match the route was right
       if (url === wpDataUrl) {
         return true;
       }

       // Otherwise get the right data to match the routes
       // (Utilize the asynchronicity here that UrlMatcher does not have)

       const navId = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().id; // Angular 7.2+
       let newWpData = await this.wp.getByUrl(url);

       // Abort if this navigation is obsolete
       if (navId !== this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.id) {
         return false;
       }

       // Update the data for the route re-matching
       wpData = newWpData;
       wpDataUrl = url;

       // Preferred option for re-matching the routes:
       return this.router.parseUrl(url); // Angular 7.1+

       // Hacky option:
       // First redirect to a different route
       await this.router.navigateByUrl('/loading', { skipLocationChange: true });
       // Now the router will re-match the routes for the original URL
       await this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
       return false;
     }
   }
   ```

   ```ts
   const wpRouteMatcher: UrlMatcher = (
     segments: UrlSegment[],
     group: UrlSegmentGroup,
     route: Route
   ) => {
     return (wpData == null // match any route the first time
       || wpData.contentType === (route.data as any).wpContentType)
       ? { consumed: segments }
       : null;
   };

   const routes: Routes = [
     // {
     //  path: 'loading',
     //  component: LoadingComponent
     // },
     // ...
     {
       path: '',
       canActivateChild: [CanActivateChildWpApi],
       children: [
         {
           matcher: wpRouteMatcher,
           component: PostComponent,
           data: { wpContentType: 'post' },
         },
         {
           matcher: wpRouteMatcher,
           component: PageComponent,
           data: { wpContentType: 'page' },
         },
         // ...
       ]
     },
   ];
   ```
2. **[Dynamically load components](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)** using custom logic inside a component that has a standard route.
3. **Expose the module injector** as a variable by capturing it when bootstrapping the app, [as shown in a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60432821/1726637). This will make it possible to directly resolve dependencies using Angular's DI, but still **doesn't let you match routes asynchronously**.

   ```ts
   // app-injector.ts or some other file

   import { Injector } from '@angular/core';

   export let appInjector: Injector = null;

   export function setAppInjector(newAppInjector: Injector) {
     appInjector = newAppInjector;
   }
   ```

   ```ts
   // main.ts

   import { setAppInjector } from './app-injector';

   platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(ref => {
     // ...
     setAppInjector(ref.injector);
   });
   ```

   ```ts
   import { appInjector } from './app-injector';
   import { FooService } from './foo.service';

   // Anywhere else, including inside a UrlMatcher
   const fooService = appInjector.get<FooService>(FooService);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

1.In `main.ts`:

```
export let appInjector: Injector;


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
      .then(m => appInjector = m.injector)
```

2. In your router module:

`import {appInjector} from '../../main';`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
     matcher: (segments: UrlSegment[]): UrlMatchResult => {
       if (appInjector.get(AccessService).hasAccess('test')) {
         return {consumed: [segment]};
       }
   },
   component: TestComponent,
];
```

Comment: Isn't it circular dependency?

Comment: No, I use it successfully

Comment: Got circular dependency warning:

client:135 Circular dependency detected:
src/app/app.module.ts -> src/app/app.router.ts -> src/main.ts -> src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: I didn't use import from main in the app module or app routing module. In your case, try to save the app injector in a different file